# How to read the flagging summary?

Tags: support, flags, flag-history

The [new flagging summary](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/84757/flag-weight-audit/85150#85150) (click on your number of helpful flags in your profile) is cool, however some posts have a gray background, some don't. What does it mean?

example:
[image]

Comment: @Charles: Do you know _when_ this summary was introduced? Has it already been there some time?

Comment: According to [Grace Note post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/84757/flag-weight-audit/85150#85150) it appeared yesterday

Comment: This is about a menu/tab only available to mods, right?

Comment: @Cawas it's available to everyone, click on your flag weight in profile page, or go to http://stackoverflow.com/users/flag-weight/<userid>

Comment: Charles, your URL works, but I still can't find "flag weight" in my profile or anywhere! I must be even more custom blind right now. :P

Comment: @Cawas I think your flag weight is not always visible in your profile, but don't know the condition (edit [Grace's post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/84757/flag-weight-audit/85150#85150) says "not visible if flag-weight sitting at 100")

Answer (score 24, accepted):

What I've been able to work out:

- The posts with grey backgrounds are deleted.
- The number is the vote count of that post.
- The text with a yellow background is the moderator message you flagged the post with (thanks Grace).
- The last line shows the current state of the post. If there's nothing there then it means that the post is still open.
- The word *helpful* or *decline* is displayed when the flag has been dealt with.

<strike>There doesn't seem to be an indication of whether the flag was marked as valid or not.</strike>

A flag *could* be dismissed as valid, but no action taken. Equally it could be dismissed as invalid while there was still an action taken. It will depend on the moderator reviewing that flag.

Comment: Yellow is actually the moderator message you flagged the post with. When you choose a close reason as a flag message (via "does not belong"), it is the close reason, but it can also be an entirely different message if you opt to custom-write your flag. Other than that, I like the comprehensiveness of your answer.

Comment: Great. The one relevant bit of information -- whether my flagging is any good -- isn't given.

Comment: So far as I can tell, the last line shows the current state of the post, not whether it got that way due to your flag. I flagged a locked post to ask for a bad tag to be removed, and the last line says "♦ Post Locked".

Comment: @Gabe - That's what I meant, I'll make it clearer.

Comment: That said, I *wish* it included the action taken or whether the flag was valid.

Comment: It seems the last line shows ALL manual moderator actions since one has flagged, @Gabe. It can be [quite a long list](http://i.imgur.com/0q1Rk.png), for which surely not [all actions](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/59445/timeline) are related to the flag one raised.

Comment: (And [another example](http://i.imgur.com/WIaal.png), but meanwhile deleted so its timeline [is 10k only](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/2420689/timeline), if still present.)

Comment: Some of the entries have a number in parentheses next to the post title (in grey), what do those mean?  You can see an example in the last entry in ChrisF's screenshot.

Comment: Never mind, I figured out what those are, those tell you how many answers the question had.

Comment: (The images for "can be [quite a long list](http://i.stack.imgur.com/0q1Rk.png)" and "[another example](http://i.stack.imgur.com/WIaal.png)" in my Mar 31 '11 comments above, should nowadays include `stack` in their URLs.)

Comment: Working links to Arjan's two in-comment images above:  "[quite a long list](http://i.stack.imgur.com/0q1Rk.jpg)" and "[another example](http://i.stack.imgur.com/WIaal.jpg)".

Answer (score 7):

A grey background indicates a question that is deleted. If you are sub-10k, this lets you view resolutions to flags that you normally would not even be able to.

Answer (score 1):

Certain flags are invalidated if they are of sufficient age.

Aging rules are here: [When are moderator flags automatically dismissed as "aged away" by the system?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/204327/when-are-moderator-flags-automatically-dismissed-as-aged-away-by-the-system)

> When a flag is aged like this, you see "aged away" for the flag reason...