# Show "helpful flags" counter and link on the mobile site profile page

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, profile-page, mobile-web, flag-history

There is no "**helpful flags**" counter (with a link to [flagging summary](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/85151/158912)) on the mobile version of profile page. And I see no other way to reach flagging summary page and check your flagging history from mobile rather than switching to the full site view.

**Desktop version**

[image: profile page on the desktop browser]
 
**Mobile version**

[image: profile page on the mobile site]

Comment: On the mobile site, I'd personally rather have a bit less info (and flag weight is one thing I'm specifically willing to sacrifice) than a higher bandwidth cost for an already 'busy' page.

Comment: @RobMoir `…higher bandwidth cost…` - does additional 100 bytes really make difference for you?

Comment: Where does the cutoff point begin then? 100 bytes here and 100 bytes there and pretty soon you're saving some real bandwidth. If something doesn't need to be there (and *in my opinion* this does not) then it should be trimmed.

Comment: @RobMoir OK - I see your point. IMHO much more useless fields are already there: your own email, age and location. I think flag weight deserves its place near them or even instead one of them (I wouldn't miss much the email field for example :-)). Let's see what will the Community decide. Currently it's: +2/-2.

Comment: even less useful fields <--- totally agree with that; I'd be happy to see the info that's already there trimmed for the mobile page. As you say, let the community decide, and then let the devs decide if they want to bother anyway ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hooray! This is finally done in the [new profile page redesign](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/249951/help-us-test-the-shiny-new-user-activity-page-plus-a-bunch-of-new-features):

> [image]

Clicking it still opens the actual flag history page in the full site theme only, but still - a great improvement. :)

This is currently available only here on MSE, but [will be rolled network wide very soon](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/249951/help-us-test-the-shiny-new-user-activity-page-plus-a-bunch-of-new-features/249980#comment822922_249980).

Comment: @Pat well, the real minimal version is now in the app, so the mobile web could "allow itself" to be more friendly - guess that's their motive.

Comment: sorry, I meant the full log like in the full web. The number is okay from my pov.

Comment: @Pat I see - the team mentioned the mobile version is still not final, so they might take some things away. Guess we just have to wait and see. :)

Comment: Whoa! Can't believe my eyes. I hope it will be present in the final version.

Answer (score 5):

In particular, for the mobile site, it seems like the following fields wouldn't be necessary:

- Real Name
- Age
- Location
- Website
- Email

Unless you're managing multiple accounts, that all seems like superfluous information.

Comment: Yes, I agree with you (I guess we will need to post another feature-request if we want to get rid of them). What about flag weight link? Would like it to be there?

Comment: @Idolon yes, I would like to see the flag weight link and have upvoted the question accordingly.

Answer (score 4):

I want te flag weight to be there as much as I want rep to be there. Some people ask and answer, others edit. Many people do both. Flag weight is the rep of editing and it should be shown on mobile, even if it doesn't link to a breakdown.

Comment: "Flag weight is the rep of editing". I think you're extremely confused about what flag weight is