# Can we get the flag history on the mobile version?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, flags, mobile-web, flag-history

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Provide the “helpful flags” link on the mobile site](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/113494/provide-the-helpful-flags-link-on-the-mobile-site)

I've been flagging some posts through the mobile friendly version of SO and although there is no guarantee that flagged posts are handled right away, the hope never dies ;)

But I'm not able to see if someone responded to my flag on the mobile version, which means I need to either frequently visit the flagged posts or wait until I get to a desktop computer to find out if the flag has been reviewed.

I'd like to have the flag history on the mobile version - its a *nice to have* functionality.

Comment: Agreed, this is about the only reason I change to the full site view when on my mobile. This, and deleting comments.

Comment: See: [Provide the “helpful flags” link on the mobile site](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/113494/provide-the-helpful-flags-link-on-the-mobile-site)