# Mobile Flagging History

Tags: feature-request, mobile-web, flag-history

[This meta question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/136853/can-we-get-the-flag-history-on-the-mobile-version) asks the same and is flagged as a duplicate of [this other meta question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/113494/show-helpful-flags-counter-and-link-on-the-mobile-site-profile-page), which despite the fact that it is answered and that the answer earned a bounty, **does not actually answer the question that was asked in any way**.

The question is "Can we get flagging history on the mobile version of the site".

The accepted answer is about "what fields are shown in the mobile user profile, that we could get rid of" - which answers to *comments* made, but not the *actual* question. **And there's no status tag on the question**.

When [cdn.sstatic.net](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/191788/cdn-sstatic-net-is-having-me-stare-at-a-plain-white-browser) isn't being a pain in the neck, the mobile version of SO shows up in a totally reasonable amount of time, I don't see what the big deal is with having "an extra 100 bytes" being sent over to provide a hyperlink to yet another page.

The point being, this missing feature makes the mobile version seem incomplete, and that sucks.

I hereby formally request the flagging history to be included in the mobile version :)

**EDIT**

I think it's worth mentioning that **the mobile version of the site allows you to flag posts**; therefore I think it makes sense to also **allow following up on those flags** using the mobile version.

You can edit a post and follow up on your suggested edits **with the mobile version**; *you can even see who is approving/rejecting your edits and see how many edits these users have approved and rejected* - and editing a post is quite a pain in the neck with a mobile device; it's possible, but you just wish you had a real keyboard. And yet the mobile version has it full-featured... or so it seems.

Either disable flagging posts from a mobile device (doesn't make sense right?), or enable following up on them. That's what I meant with "*this missing feature makes the mobile version seem incomplete*".

Comment: The "addtional data" argument doesn't hold - what's one more hyperlink on the user profile page, when the main page (questions list) holds... well just how many hyperlinks?!

Comment: The answer there doesn't mean anything. It's a suggestion for what they could get rid of *in order to implement this feature* - an expansion off the question. Likely the OP accepted it because they agreed strongly with it, not because it solved the issue.

Comment: Yes, and then it seems the idea of having a mobile version of the flagging history just went to oblivion... I find it's a legitimate feature request that *at least* deserves a status!

Comment: There are plenty of feature requests out there that sit around for quite a long time without any status. It's likely not something that the SE development team is really worried about right now. They have a *lot* of other projects.

Comment: Of course, the mobile version *is* incomplete. That's what differentiates it from the "full" version (which is, by the way, also available on mobile devices just like it is on non-mobile devices).

Comment: I thought the main difference between a *full* and a *mobile* version was merely to rework the layout to fit a smaller display, to ease scrolling and therefore viewing. Ideally a mobile version would implement every feature of the full-fledged one, I find. But I don't do mobile dev, maybe I'm just ignorant, but I just can't see what it is that prevents a single little hyperlink from showing up there, other than "well it's a dumbed-down version, we don't need that".

Comment: No, I don't imagine there's any *technical* reason why this couldn't be added to the mobile site. But the point is to make the site *simpler* for the limited screens and less-sophisticated UX of a mobile device. Keeping all the same features and simply "reworking the layout" would take quite a bit of skill, probably more than is reasonable to expect. It's not like this is unprecedented. iMovie and GarageBand on the iPhone are great and surprisingly full-featured, but they're still lacking compared to the full desktop versions. They'd be untenable otherwise.