# I'm able to access the review queues from my mobile

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, review, mobile-web, hidden-features

I understand [the mobile version is deliberately missing some features](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/191871/mobile-flagging-history), so I'm not surprised to not see a "Review" link in the top bar.

However I can access my profile, bring up the "Activity" view, select any "Suggested Edit" I have made, rejected or approved, and then I'm magically taken to the full-featured version of the site; from there I can access all the review queues I normally have access to, and start reviewing, say, suggested edits (here, my last 5 reviews were made from my mobile!).

**If we're not supposed to be reviewing using the mobile version, then why is it possible to do it through the "back door"?**

Besides, I find the format of the review queues is fairly suitable for mobile (given minor layout adjustments), I think it should eventually be implemented.

Comment: It's just a theme, bunch of different CSS files and maybe JS - some of the pages have been customized to fit better in a mobile device that's all. The team can't and should not block the ability to browse the full site from a mobile device. It's not a bug and not a hidden feature.

Comment: I see. But I'm a *user* (who shouldn't need to care if it's CSS, JS, or whatever), and from a *user experience* standpoint, it makes the review queues look like a feature that can only be accessed by "cheating" through some "back door". Just throwing in my two cents here, whether it's a bug or not (or a hidden feature) doesn't really matter, feel free to retag to something more appropriate (meta-rant?). Cheers!

Comment: There is a special hell reserved for website designers who make desktop features deliberately unavailable for mobile users

Comment: In all fairness you're right; it should stay within the mobile format but until thats implemented being thrown out to the desktop version is infinitely better than it not being available at all