# 'Helpful flags count' and 'profile views' on mobile site

Tags: discussion, feature-request, profile-page, mobile-web, helpful-flags

Can we add 'Helpful flags count' and 'profile views' on mobile site/devices?

I'm aware of the following old question (and which may get this post marked as a duplicate) but I'm keen on providing, where possible, an appropriate and valid experience regardless of the device used by users:

> [Show "helpful flags" counter and link on the mobile site profile page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/113494/show-helpful-flags-counter-and-link-on-the-mobile-site-profile-page)

Is there a reason why both can't be listed in the mobile view of SO? I log in frequently using a desktop, tablet and mobile device (depending on where I am and what I might be doing) and it seems we're missing a trick here to unify functionality and information across devices.

There are [arguments](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/114409/199767) in the above mentioned question as to what items are less important/displayed and I agree that these items are far more valuable than knowing my own age, location, email etc.

As a multi-device user, I'd prefer to see elements listed that *can* and *do* change rather than echo static data and exclude dynamic information based upon what device is used to access SO and other SE sites.

Comment: Well, I'm sure the real reason is that linking the helpful flag count in the mobile layout would also require *building* a mobile version of the flagging summary. But then again, they link to the revisions history and don't have a mobile-friendly version of that (and it bugs the hell out of me suddenly being on the full site).

Comment: @animuson It's bugs the hell out of me too that I can't see or do certain things via mobile, but appreciate that some elements are beyond others and aren't practical. Building a mobile version of the flagging summary wouldn't take that long to do though...

Comment: *"Building a mobile version of the flagging summary wouldn't take that long to do though..."* [citation-required]