# How to see helpful flags in web version(not mobile application)

Tags: discussion, flags, mobile-web

Is there a way to see the **helpful flags** via **my profile** in **mobile version**? Everytime I want to see it, I need to **request for desktop site**, then I could view the helpful flags.

I searched the site for a similar question to avoid a duplicate question, however, I only found questions related to the actions/concerns/features related to helpful flags.

Please note that my question is about the web version of the site and not about the mobile application.

Also, I am not sure if this ought to be a feture request, since I don't know if this functionality is already available in the web version.

Comment: You can't see, it simply does not exist in the mobile theme. If you mean you ask for this feature, [it's already asked](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/113494/show-helpful-flags-counter-and-link-on-the-mobile-site-profile-page).

Comment: UPDATE: this is actually done in the new design, currently available only here on MSE.

Comment: Duh! So, I am correct that such a feature is not available with web version. Thanks for the link, I see the feature request was already made.

Comment: Ok, so the feature is on it's way to be rolled out for all the sites?

Comment: Yes indeed, [as Stack Exchange VP says himself](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/249951/help-us-test-the-shiny-new-user-activity-page-plus-a-bunch-of-new-features/249980#comment822922_249980)

Comment: Wow. That puts a full stop to the discussion ;-) Thanks a lot @Shadow

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There isn't really at the moment. You could propose this, but I don't know if it is really useful.

<strike>A workaround could be setting your 'next badge' in the new user profile to Marshal. That way you will see your progress towards it. The number there is the number of helpful flags you have raised.</strike>

Oh my, they added the text itself now. You still can see the details only on the full web site.

> [image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer. +1. Is this valid for other sites as well? I am more interested with Stack Overflow.

Comment: No, there isn't until the new layout is rolled out.

Comment: Ok, I see. It's going to be a new feature. @shadow commented the same. Thanks. +1 This answers my question. So, accepting it as an answer.

Comment: Perhaps, I need to wait a while to accept it as an answer, that's what the message says when I accepted the answer. I feel so bad that I am unaware if so many features here, I should spend some time on `META` too :-)

Comment: umm... new design does have the stat no need for any workarounds.

Comment: Must justify my name... :D Oh wait, you mean you? :P

Comment: Done. Accepted as an answer. Took a while though :-)