# Flags: Rejected or lost

Tags: support, flags, flag-history

Are these on-topic?

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19861242/send-oft-template-with-outlook

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19794731/embedded-pictures-in-the-body-of-the-email-is-not-visible-in-windows-7-outlook-2

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14387598/sharepoint-2010-discussion-board-outlook-2007

I flagged them but it appears the flags were rejected or lost. Is there somewhere to see why a flag was rejected?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to read the flagging summary?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/85151/how-to-read-the-flagging-summary)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you visit [your profile](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1571407/), there should be a link to your flag history:

[image]

You click on your helpful flag count, which will bring up a list of everything you've flagged. Flags marked helpful were determined by a moderator(s) to be valid, flags with an **active** designation are still in the moderator queue (or the close vote queue if they are close flags), and flags marked **declined** (in red) were found by the moderator(s) to be not valid.

Comment: That's a nice amount of flags you got there :)

Comment: Your flag-fu is still weak. ;)

Comment: Keep flagging maybe you'll catch up to @AndrewBarber's total flags.

Comment: @bluefeet I've calculated it out (like, on a piece of paper), and I should catch up by mid Spring '14 :)

Comment: Hmmm... time to start trolling and declining Undo's flags. ;) /cc @bluefeet

Comment: @AndrewBarber decline, decline.....decline all of them!

Comment: @bluefeet especially if you've flagged, too! ;)

Comment: @andrew NOOOOO!!!!!!!!!

Answer (score 4):

If you mean "lost" as in, still marked as active, thats because your close-flags get routed into a "close vote queue", which currently has a backlog of 95,545 items.

In terms of whether they're off topic or not; yes, they're all close worthy in my opinion.

- The first should be closed as:

  > Questions concerning problems with code you've written must describe the specific problem — and include valid code to reproduce it — in the question itself. See SSCCE.org for guidance.
- The second should also be closed as:

  > Questions concerning problems with code you've written must describe the specific problem — and include valid code to reproduce it — in the question itself. See SSCCE.org for guidance.
- The third would either be closed as *primarily opinion-based* or *unclear what you're asking*.