# On flags to migrate a question, why was the site I selected no longer shown in the flag history?

Tags: support, flags, flag-history

In a very distant past (before the closing overhaul), I vaguely remember that if I cast a recommend closure flag on a question, it would show in my personal flag history as "off-topic; belongs on [site]". (**Update:** After a bit of clicking, I found [another post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/85151/377214) which contains a screenshot of how such flags used to look like.)

However, after the 2013 four-part overhaul of the close reasons, those flags just show up as "off-topic" (today "Not suitable for this site"), with the display of prior flags retroactively changed to that.

Why was that change made?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Back then, "belongs on another site" was also the only available sub-reason for off-topic. You could either vote it as plain off-topic for the site or choose a migration path.

With the overhaul, we introduced the moderator-customizable sub-reasons for the off-topic section. Those reasons are often too long, and of varying length, to display in the flag history in a nice way. The easiest solution was to just not display the sub-reasons there at all. This also affected the "belongs on" reasons as we did not add any special casing for them.

The past flags were not "retroactively changed" - just the way we display the flag history now does not include the secondary piece of information for the flag.