# Why is this flag marked as "Disputed"?

Tags: support, flags, flag-history

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is a disputed flag?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/95275/what-is-a-disputed-flag)

I have a flag marked as Disputed under my flagging summary. What does it mean? Did I flag incorrectly?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [answer you flagged](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7252037/resetting-classpath-after-doing-export-classpath/7252055#7252055) is an answer. Maybe not a correct one, but still an answer.

The "Not an answer" flag is for contributions that are completely unintelligible, or clearly do not address the question at all (like "I have the same problem" type answers.)