# Why are there different messages after I select "invalid flag"

Tags: support, flags, 10k-tools

I've read [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/112392/am-i-using-the-invalid-flag-flag-wrongly), so I understand that every time I select "invalid flag" the *original* flag will become disputed, and will be listed as such in my flagging summary.  But why do most of these flags show up in my flagging summary like this:

> invalid flag – 17 hours ago   disputed

but one or two show up like this

> invalid flag – 19 hours ago   disputed - a moderator reviewed your flag, but found no evidence to support it

Is there a difference?  Does the latter mean that an actual moderator took the time to look at the original flag, and *also* selected invalid, while the former indicates that no moderator ever looked at it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The latter message only shows up when a moderator clicks the radio button in a "dismiss flags" dialog that is captioned *"A moderator reviewed your flag, but found no evidence to support it."*

I assume your former example came from the `/tools/flagged` page, where reviewers can "disagree" with a flag. Flags that *already* have a "disagree" on them can be dismissed by a moderator without providing additional explanation.