# Disputed Flag - Impact on Daily Flag Count

Tags: support, flags

Reference: [What is a disputed flag?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/95275/what-is-a-disputed-flag)

A user has specific number of Flag counts in his/her kitty. What I mean is, a user can flag only a certain amount of times in a day.

My question is, if I have say 10 flags left that I can use in a day and if I dispute a flag, will the count go down to 9 or will it remain at 10?

If it remains at 10 then I understand but if it goes down to 9 then I want to understand why does that happen as the `Dispute` Flag doesn't have any flag weight so why should it even effect the Daily Flag Count?

Thanks for reading.

Comment: It should *cost* something to dispute someone else's flag, too.

Comment: Thank you for the comment. So are you confirming in a way that the remaining count will go down to 9?

Comment: It does indeed go down, yes. I should have been clear about that!

Comment: Thank you. Then back to my question. If it `should` cost something then it is equally logical that it should effect the flag weight as well :)

Comment: Not necessarily. You are doing the same thing to the other party; eliminating their flag weight by saying they flagged incorrectly. The same does not apply when you issue a normal flag.

Comment: If it is an incorrect flag.. it is an incorrect flag. No two things about it. Tomorrow if I flag something incorrectly.. too bad... my flag weight should get affected :)

Comment: Why does this matter?  [Flag weight is no longer visible!](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/84859/we-dont-need-to-see-flag-weight)

Comment: @kevin Vermeer: My question is not about making the disputed `flag` weigh. My question is about the Flag Count. If the disputed flag doesn't have any flag weight then why does it even effect the flag count?

Answer (score 4):

Flagging does cost you a flag, yes. :-)

If a disputed flag was for free, someone in a rage could get the idea to dispute every flag in the flag queue. We don't want to leave that option open, do we?

Comment: I'd like to see counter flags on automated Community ♦ flags be free though. It's extremely helpful to us when people investigate vandalism, excessive comments, etc ... and counter flag when nothing really warrants our attention (Community is one of the noisiest flaggers we have)

Comment: Thanks Bo :) But is that really the reason? If a moderator confirms it. I will accept your answer :)