# Custom flag incorrectly declined

Tags: discussion, flags, declined-flags

I flagged [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15273113/perl-to-php-function) ("convert my perl code to PHP") as "Too localized and off topic". My flag was declined.

The reason I flagged it that way instead of using the closing tool is that I had used my 50 closings for one day.

Since I flagged it, the question was closed as "too localized", which seems to prove that I wasn't the only one thinking that it was.

Can someone explain me why this flag got declined? I don't really mind as my accepted/declined flags ratio is high enough, but I'd like to understand.

Comment: ... what was the decline reason?

Comment: Where can I find it ? It only says "declined - a moderator reviewed your flag, but found no evidence to support it"

Comment: Heh, that is the decline reason; *a moderator reviewed your flag, but found no evidence to support it*. Only the moderator who declined your flag can answer for definite, but this might have been a simple mistake, or you might find that your flag was bundled in with other *wrong* flags, and the moderator had to decline them; which bundles yours with it, unfortunately.

Comment: Too localized, sure, but off topic?

Comment: @DavidRobinson Yeah I think you're right, I suppose I considered it something like a code review, but it is more like a "Write code for me" question. But still.

Comment: @Matt What do you mean, bundled with other wrong flags ?

Comment: AFAIK, if a post receives (for example) a "offensive" and a "low quality" flag, moderators can either mark both flags as "helpful", or "decline" them both; you can't accept one and reject the other.

Comment: Oh, got it. That's a weird way of dealing with wrong flags, but I suppose this is a useful tool, given the bunch of flags they surely get notified with daily.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In this case, that post received two flags.  One of the flags was yours, the other was another user that flagged the post as something that was quite incorrect (think flagging a post as spam that isn't).

We [don't have the ability](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/142264/my-flags-are-disputed-but-flagged-posts-are-deleted/142266#142266) to accept one flag and decline the other, [so both get declined](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/160754/why-are-the-moderators-being-so-strict-with-quality-related-flags-recently).

Comment: You can explicitly clear spam/offensive flags first (mod->clear offensive flags on the post), though I don't think that marks them "declined" as such.

Comment: @AnnaLear That's good to know (though a little cumbersome from the mod panel), though there are certainly situations where two custom flags are at odds.  From the mod panel, would I do the following: Expand post; clear flags using dropdown; refresh mod page; find post; mark remaining flag as helpful? Or is the system smart enough for me to just clear the spam flag using the dropdown and then marking post flag as helpful?

Comment: That's a great question that I unfortunately don't know the answer to.

Comment: Ok, that confirms Matt's thoughts. Thanks for clarifying that.