# Why was my flag for "too localized" declined, but the question closed with the "too localized" reason?

Tags: discussion, flags, closed-questions, declined-flags

I flagged [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15716426/maodv-tcl-script-error-o17-cmd-line-1) as too localized. Today I looked at my flagging history and saw that my flag was declined with the message

> flagging questions to beg for help is abuse of the flagging system. it is only meant if something needs moderator attention but never a way to ask for answers!

But the question was closed (as I did ask for) as too localized.

So I ask myself (any now you)

- Was my flag not correct?
- Would an other reason be better suited?
- How did I gave the view that I ask for an answer here?

Or:

- What have I done wrong?

Comment: Most likely the OP had flagged their own post asking for an answer. Mods can't chose a specific message for each flag on a post, they all get declined or accepted with the same message.

Comment: I understand. I felt right about my flag, and it was declined. Ok, happens (first time for me), but the reason was.. ehh, I did something wrong? What? How?

Comment: @Mat while this sounds true, do you have link to more details?

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/170669/custom-flag-incorrectly-declined?rq=1 for instance, @ShaWizDowArd

Comment: @Mat nice, think this question should be closed as dupe of the other one then? That answer fits here perfectly as well..

Comment: I can confirm that @Mat is right, the OP flagged the post as well.  Your flag was correct.  Sorry about the mix-up.