# Is it bad that I have so many disputed flags?

Tags: discussion, flags, disputed-flags

On one site (Stack Overflow), I have 211 disputed flags and 333 helpful flags. That is, I have **more than half** as many disputed flags as helpful flags. **38%** of my non-pending, non-aged-away post flags are disputed.

I know [disputed flags don't count against me](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/95275/295684), but are these statistics indicative of a problem with my flagging behavior? Only 5 of my flags have been declined, but a lot of the flags I raise are in the Triage queue, and I think I remember reading that Triage flags can't get declined. I don't have enough rep to review close votes, so [these answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/112392/295684) don't apply.

Am I too trigger-happy with flags, or is something else going on here?

Comment: Triage flags can be declined, although it's not all that common. Much more common is the auto-disputation if the Triage result comes up Looks OK, which used to also include Should Be Improved. If you routinely review in Triage, hundreds of disputed flags are the norm. (Having so few helpful flags relative to those disputed flags is a bit less common.)

Comment: Since this is specific to [so] you might get better responses on Meta Stack Overflow.

Comment: @ɥʇǝS I'm not sure if it actually is SO-specific; disputed flags can appear outside of Triage. But then again, it'd be hard to get this many disputed flags without Triage. Hmm.

Comment: Yes but whether you are using the flags right is highly site specific so..