# Allow disputed flags to be re-raised

Tags: feature-request, flags, disputed-flags

Since some flags are handled by non-moderators, they may be marked as "disputed" and effectively thrown away. I review a lot in Stack Overflow's Triage queue, so this happens to me with [appalling frequency](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/269812/295684). (Disputed flags can appear outside of the Triage queue, of course, so I'm posting this in the network-wide meta.) I believe a lot of those flags are valid, so I go to re-flag, but then I get this:

[image: "you have already raised this type of flag"]

I know I can raise a custom flag, but that would get rather tedious, and I'd be afraid of forcing mods to read yet more text, and of getting the flags declined with a message about using the normal reasons.

I propose that disputed flags not block the re-flagging of the post. There should probably be a guarantee that the second flag be handled by a real mod. A note in the flag dialog about an existing disputed flag might be appropriate.

"[Once a flag is cleared from the mod queue, the same post cannot be re-flagged](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/61916/295684)" and "[Allow users to flag questions more than once](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/46472/295684)" are [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed), saying that flags can be re-raised *after being looked at by a moderator*, and disputed flags never get looked at by mods, so this seems to be a separate request and not a [bug](/questions/tagged/bug).

Comment: A user with close-vote rights can also vote only once to close a question, even if the question doesn't get closed in the end. Why would that be different for flags?

Comment: @BartvanIngenSchenau There's [a highly-voted feature request](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/99333/295684) to allow the re-casting of expired close votes. Even if that doesn't go through, it could make sense for 3K-ers to be able to flag (just like 15-ers) the question, risking a declined flag if they're wrong but getting a bad question closed if they're right.

Comment: Recasting close votes has actually been [completed for some time](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/250223/age-close-votes-after-14-days-regardless-of-views-allowing-recasting). cc @BartvanIngenSchenau