# Should flagging be used to advocate in opposition to another user's flag?

Tags: discussion, flags

Within the comments of [Running Time of a d-ary heap?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11166235/running-time-of-a-d-ary-heap), there is a fairly strong indication that at least one user flagged the question as being better suited to another forum.  I disagreed, and advocated in support of leaving the question where it was, but I also considered flagging the question myself, but not to recommend it being moved.  Instead, I wanted to advocate directly with the moderators in support of the position I made in the comments.  However, I was not sure the flag system was really intended to serve that purpose. So my question:

Is advocating that no moderator action be taken in response to another user's flag (when it seems likely such a flag has been raised) an appropriate use of the flag system?

Comment: For what it's worth, the flag on this particular question you refer to has already been handled, so you don't need to flag to oppose it anymore.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, this is appropriate. In fact, in the [10k moderation tools](https://stackoverflow.com/privileges/moderator-tools), you're able to look at an existing flag on a question and explicitly deem it invalid (thereby marking it *disputed*; see [What is a disputed flag?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/95275/what-is-a-disputed-flag)).

However, as you can tell you're not able to do that if you're not yet at 10k reputation. If this option is not available to you but you think the question may have been flagged, feel free to raise a custom flag explaining why you disagree with said flag and we'll look into it.

Answer (score 4):

Yep. Mods are human exception handlers, and this here is an "exception". I personally would look for a mod in chat, but if I don't find one and there's *anything* post/user related that I want to tell a mod, a custom flag is the way to go.

In this particular case, however, I don't feel it is particularly *necessary*. The mods probably look through the comments on the post before taking any action. But there's no harm in flagging it, IMO{*}

<sup>**Cue angry comments from SO mods*</sup>