# Having issues with declined flags, I don't get it right

Tags: support, flags, declined-flags

I've just wanted to ask this question:

> Difference between declined and disputed

Than I've found this question which is too similar to what I have [What is the difference between disputed and declined flags?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/141292/what-is-the-difference-between-disputed-and-declined-flags)

The answer is that question is very good, but it triggered my current question, to make it short, in the answer there is:

> which (roughly) influences how "important" your flags should be considered by moderators.

What does this exactly mean ? will I some day get my flag privileges revoked because of that ?

---

#### EDIT

in another way: **what does mean *declined* flags affect my flagging privileges? in which way it affect it?**

Comment: No; 'disputed' flags will not affect your flagging privileges. Only rejected flags do.

Comment: what that is mean to affect my flagging privileges ? this is what I don't get :S

Comment: @AbuRomaïssae: If you flag lots of posts that are rejected then your ability to flag further posts is withdrawn for a period of time.

Comment: Also, people who flag correctly most of the time get a few extra flags and their flags appear closer to the front of the queue.

Comment: related topic: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/79742/are-the-new-moderator-flag-limits-sufficiently-high

Comment: @JonW Not quite. If enough flags are rejected, your ability to flag things is *permanently* disabled, after a fashion. You'll still be able to flag things, but nobody will see those flags unless looking at the flag history of a post you flagged for some other reason. Right now there's no way to recover from this, though there probably should be. It's fairly low-priority though, since in most cases if someone hits that, they *really* haven't been paying attention.

Comment: @AnnaLear really? I always thought it worked in the same way as the multiple rejected edit ban worked. Oh well, TIL.

Comment: @JonW That's actually a good idea. I'm making a mental note. :)