# Show question suggestions of MetaSO on per-site-Metas

Tags: feature-request, questions, meta, per-site-meta

> **No, this is not a duplicate:**
> I'm talking about *all* MSO questions in the suggested questions list, while @MadScientist wants to be able to view the faq posts on all per-site metas. *That's a difference.*

We have a lot questions on child metas that could be easily closed as a duplicate of a MetaSO question. While implementing a cross-site duplicate function might be a nasty job, perhaps it's easier to suggest "Questions that may already have your answer", also from MetaSO.

So, when one is going to ask a question about [the difference between declined and disputed flags](https://electronics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2809/17592) on a child meta, he would get a list of questions which includes [What is the difference between disputed and declined flags?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/141292/205264), which is a MetaSO question.

**This would help us get better answers and in the meanwhile clean up the meta sites.**

The [chat with an expert](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/174407/205264) hype of today has shown that this can be really useful: [here](https://electronics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2821/17592), [here](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3437/23992), [here](https://meta.askubuntu.com/q/6402/125111), [here](https://meta.superuser.com/q/6582/187676), [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/8953/63495) and [here](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3869) are *all* child meta questions about Chat with an Expert. People have wasted there time making and cropping screenshots, explaining their questions, answering them, etc.

Comment: [I've previously proposed to include FAQ questions from Meta.SO on all child metas](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/171655/make-network-wide-faq-posts-available-on-per-site-metas). The idea behind this is very similar.

Comment: To make this clear: it is **not** a duplicate. I'm talking about _all_ MSO questions in the suggested questions list, while @MadScientist wants to be able to view the [meta-tag:faq] posts on all per-site metas. _That's a difference_.

Comment: Meh, One can just give a link and a short description on these. Cross-network dupes  on metas aren't a big problem.

Comment: @Manishearth not for answering, but people are using their time on writing those posts, that's what I'm worried about as well.

Comment: @CamilStaps: It takes about 10 seconds to write such an answer once you have the dupe link. I spend a lot of time on MSO as well as child metas of the sites I moderate, I deal with these in literally less than 30 seconds if I'm online. I don't mind.

Comment: @Manishearth It indeed doesn't take much time to deal with them. I'm talking about the people writing the questions. Sorry for the misunderstanding.

Comment: @CamilStaps: ah, I see. However, there would be way too much clutter from MSO. Take a gander at the number of questions here and on your meta. The suggestions would be filled with MSO options. If you tone it down, well, then it won't  find stuff on MSO in the first place. The "possible dupe" algorithm is rather weak.

Answer (score 1):

Often there is information about a topic, or its practical implications, or related tips, that are specific to a certain community.

There's another reason such questions on site-specific metas are good: Sometimes, one site works differently from the others in ways people here would not expect and often do not mention. For example, on most Stack Exchange sites, users with very low rep cannot have more than 2 links in a post. But on [Skeptics](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/), they [can have 50](https://skeptics.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2083/4410). If someone found they could only post 2 links on Skeptics, that would be a bug or an indication they were doing something wrong, but they would probably never know that from searching MSO.

It's not bad for questions that have been asked here on MSO to be asked on meta 2.0 sites too. They can even sometimes be answered with answers consisting mostly of properly cited quotes from MSO.

It might be valuable to let people know they can search MSO too, but the design of the child metas is that they will get some questions that apply network-wide, and they can get answers that might include information or examples particularly relevant to the community.