# How can an "invalid flags" flag be deemed helpful?

Tags: support, flags

I always thought that flagging as "invalid flags" would make my own flag and any other flag on the post be considered "disputed", no matter what a moderator does. But my last flag was deemed "helpful", so I'm not sure anymore. I'd like to clarify that so I can update my answer to [What is the difference between disputed and declined flags?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/141292/what-is-the-difference-between-disputed-and-declined-flags).

I must say that my "invalid flags" flag was invalid, I fat-fingered the flag reason. So my questions are:

- Am I correct to suppose that the moderator marked the flags "helpful" (there were a few correct "not an answer" flags on the post already), and that caused my flag to be considered helpful as well?
- If yes, shouldn't my flag have been automatically marked "declined" instead, since it disagreed with helpful flags?

Comment: Ha, interesting... Apparently it doesn't check for invalid flags if a moderator just deletes the post and lets the system dismiss the flags?

Comment: Yes, this is how it works. The first time I checked back on a flag like that, it was seriously annoying. (Works even if they’re marked as helpful with no action.)

Comment: @animuson Is it possible to delete the post and *not* let the system handle the flags?

Comment: @minitech Should I retag this as a bug? When you say "this is how it works", it sounds like this will likely be considered status-bydesign...

Comment: From my earlier experience if a mod edits a post flagged as VLQ this dismisses the flag as "disputed" like any non mod edit would. The unexpected behavior I encountered is that it doesn't dismiss all the flags in a given group - if there's an "invalid" flag lurking it remains, split from the group and can be dismissed separately from the VLQ flag with any of the usual outcomes. I think that's a bug rather than a design decision.

Comment: @bfavaretto Well, kind of. The alternative would be to dismiss the flags manually and then delete the post.

Comment: In case it matters, this is the (deleted) post in question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9773163/vaadin-textarea-font/18004243#18004243

Comment: I still see my "invalid flags" marked as disputed when the answer is deleted. The last time this happened, it was August 13.