# Do disputed flags count towards a flag-ban?

Tags: support, flags, disputed-flags, flag-ban

A long, long time ago there once was a user who asked about [the difference between disputed and declined flags](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/141292/what-is-the-difference-between-disputed-and-declined-flags).

And it references an answer [that explains what a disputed flag is](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/95277/158100).

From that post I quote:

> Disputed flags are considered neither helpful nor declined

Is it correct to assume that disputed posts also don't count towards a flag ban?

I know the exact algorithm is a trade secret but I love the risk asking...

Comment: Please don't use "long long time ago" for something that has happened two years ago!

Comment: @JanDvorak But...it feels like ages...

Comment: According to this it seems that disputed flags count _against_ the flag ban: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/175405/194047

Comment: What sentence do you believe syas that?

Comment: "Those who've had 25% or more of their flags declined will see:" - disputed != declined

Answer (score 9):

Disputed flags don't count towards flag ban.

At present, there is a [proposed feature-request by Brad Larson](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/243145/245167) to mark a flag declined instead of disputed if the community unanimously votes against it.

From Brad's proposal:

> if these flags are unanimously voted against, mark the flags as "declined" instead of "disputed". I've been seeing some people shotgun flags of this type, since they know that **there is no penalty for getting a disputed flag**

(emphasis mine)

Also, from [psubsee2003's](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/250725/psubsee2003) [answer on MSO:](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/260596/2982225)

> Disputed flags may look "not nice" in your flag history but they are effective neutral. They don't count against you in your flag score and hence does not impact the flag ban calculation.