# Rename "Disputed" flag outcome

Tags: discussion, flags, disputed-flags, review-history

[Have changed from feature-request to discussion, as my original request was shown to have flaws. Please discuss, push ideas, call me a fool, etc]

---

### What is a "Disputed" flag outcome

A good description of the "Disputed" outcome from bjb568's [answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/141400/230506):

> When you flag an answer as NAA or VLQ and the post doesn't result in
>   deletion but someone recommended deletion, the flag is disputed. Spam
>   and offensive flags on post that are rolled back are also disputed.

### Why the word is misleading

The word "disputed" isn't *usually* used to denote a *final outcome*, and so users are likely to presume a final outcome to the decision on their flag is still being decided upon.

By definition it only defines "*there was a dispute*", and not what an outcome was. In some cases this can be acceptable, but in Stack the outcome of flags need to be clear.

*Site:* "User(s) looked at your flag and it was *disputed*"
*Flagger:* "Ok, what now...? Did they eventually decide if it was 'helpful', or not?"

It also sounds negative and gives the impression the user did something wrong, when they did not, as their flag was simple "superseded" or "not used".

When a flag is raised, a possible *outcome* is:

1. Helpful
2. Declined
3. Disputed

*1* and *2* are self explanatory, and users will pretty much expect their flag to have been one or the other.
However outcome *3* only indicates "there was a dispute", but it's not clear it's the final outcome.

So, it's not obvious a "disputed" flag is a *final outcome*, it's not common knowledge *how* a "disputed" flag occurs and nor is it made obvious via the word itself.
As such I really think the word for this *outcome* should be changed to something more final and universally understood.

---

### Suggestions

Please suggest some.

I originally proposed "cancelled" which in essence is what happens to "disputed" flags, but "cancelled" seems like their flag was somehow useless and discarded - "we completely ditched your effort to report something but gave no indication why".

Requirements - The word needs to:

1. Imply a final outcome; no longer active
2. Be positive; imply user did nothing wrong
3. Not insinuate it was *helpful* or *declined*
4. Portray why it's different to and was not *helpful* or *declined*
5. Give impression it was not specifically based on their flag - i.e.
   imply it was not used due to a change, or inconclusive review

That is not a *definitive guide*, just a rough basis to work out a better word.

*OPTIONS*

[random](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/9314/random) suggested:
*Settled* and *handled*
Both are good, but neither fully cover (4) or (5) from the Requirements.

*Surplus*
Doesn't *really* cover (2); only *slightly* covers (4) and (5).

*Inconclusive*
Only *slightly* covers (2) and (4)

*Redundant*
*Arguably* covers (2) and (4);

### Issues

No matter what word is used (including current "disputed") it won't be "helpful" or "declined", and I think most users will logically be expecting one of the two.

They flagged, tried to help, and so their help was either "good" so all ok they got their flag count, or "bad" they can shrug their shoulders or dispute in Meta.

For example I really like "handled", but people are going to want to know why not "helpful".

I still think we can do better than "disputed", however.

### Why, James, why?

Why so much passion for such a thing?
Because every time I see it in my profile history it irks me a fair bit.
I still partially and briefly think "wait, disputed, what was wrong with.. oh yeah".

Comment: You don't think "cancelled" would cause more confusion? That word is generally used in situations where something was dismissed without ever being looked at in the first place, like cancelling an order. It's an "oh, nevermind" kind of word. So then instead of "when will it be handled?" we will just have "why was my flag ignored?"

Comment: @animuson I disagree with some of that. i.e. "Cancelled" is not often something which was "never looked at" - you wouldn't "cancel" an order you'd "never looked at". And you wouldn't say "oh nevermind" if this month's wage was "cancelled" :P. But overall you're right. I just cannot think of a better word. Trouble is, anything that is not "positive" is potential for a user to visit to Meta and ask/debate etc. Even something like "obsolete" which describes the scenario better is just as problematic. "I tried to help, why was my flag obsolete". Will think of something. Cheers for the feedback

Comment: Settled or handled are in between

Comment: How about "dissolved"