# What happens to closure flags if the question has been edited?

Tags: support, flags, vote-to-close

I recently came across a question that was clearly lacking enough detail to be answered in its current state. I commented, extensively showing that details were missing and the question was unclear as it was, and flagged to close as unclear (I do not have close vote privilege on the relevant site — yet).

Within something like twenty minutes (possibly less), the OP edited the question in response to my comment including the required information. The question is now no longer unclear, and easily answered. If I had cast a close vote, I would have been able to take it back, but I cast a flag, which does not expire.

Flagging for closing takes a post directly into the close votes review queue. From there, I expect three people to vote for *Leave Open* — there has been a relevant edit since, after all.

What will happen to my flag in the process? Will it end up `declined` (as the post was not closed in the queue)? That would be a shame since I had no way of knowing whether OP would respond to my comment or not. Or will something else happen ultimately?

This question is **not** a duplicate of [What is the difference between disputed and declined flags?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/141292/312026) — I am not asking for the difference between declined and disputed. The answer does not address my question either; it specifically does not mention my case (an edit between flagging and review).

This question is also **not** a duplicate of [Why does flag marking as helpful/declined not always correlate with moderator action?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/105391/312026) — The answer lists a set of conditions for flag status not matching question status but again, the *specific* case is not mentioned.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the difference between disputed and declined flags?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/141292/what-is-the-difference-between-disputed-and-declined-flags)

Comment: ^ It just says in which case the flag becomes declined - if no review agreed with the flag in the review queue.

Comment: Or this: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/105391/.

Comment: @nicael Neither of the two ask my question. They both approach a different problem from a different angle.

Comment: This doesn't matter - they *answer* your question, right?

Comment: @nicael I was under the impression (and it works that way on [chemistry.SE]) that the questions must also ask for the same difference.

Comment: @nicael I've seen it too, but since it doesn't mention editing at all, didn't vote to close.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, if none of the reviewers will cast a close vote matching your flag, it will be declined. (You only need one person agreeing with you to make the flag helpful - it doesn't depend on the total outcome of the review.)

When this question was posted (June 2016), you couldn't withdraw your flag in this case, but there were plans to enable this - the then five-year-old feature request [Cancel misclicked flags](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/87500/cancel-misclicked-flags) was implemented only a few weeks later.