# Reviewing a flagged post

Tags: discussion

When someone is reviewing a flagged post, does he see the current state of the flagged post or does he see the version of the post which existed when the post was flagged?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

He sees the current state of the flagged post.

If the flag doesn't seem to make sense, check the revision history of the post.

Comment: Shouldn't he at least be given a warning/note that the flagged post he is looking at has been changed since the time it was flagged.

Comment: Probably . . . .

Comment: I was under the impression that a flag gets automatically "disputed" when a post has been edited since the flag has been cast. Am I wrong here?

Comment: @Spontifixus: Could be.  So you're saying it doesn't matter?

Comment: Seems I was only partly right there: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/95277/195761 Only "Very Low Quality" flags get disputed when the post is being edited - so never mind...