# Why is my flag marked as disputed, but the topic is closed?

Tags: discussion, flags, disputed-flags

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is a disputed flag?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/95275/what-is-a-disputed-flag)

There are a few posts that I flag, and they get disputed.  Then a little bit later the post gets closed.  Why do my flags show up as disputed if the post got closed?

Comment: I think that is coincidence. What did you flag the post as?

Comment: if i flagged the post, and a moderator disputes it, but someone else flags it and a moderator closes it, shouldn't my flag be just as 'helpful' as the second flag?

Comment: See here - http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/95277/201262

Comment: @Ren thanks for the link

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Moderators don't dispute flags; other users with 10k reputation do. When a flag is disputed, it is considered invalid and does not have any effect on your ability to flag, nor can a moderator do anything to validate it again, even if it was valid to begin with.

Comment: I've always wondered what the purpose of the "disputed" flags were, especially when a diamond mod agrees with the original flag (and disagrees 10K user that marked the flag as invalid).  I can see how they could be a valuable teaching tool on how to flag but as a regular user, I don't really get any feedback on why the 10K user decided to mark the original flag as invalid.  Just that it was.