# Declined NAA flag?

Tags: discussion, flags, declined-flags, not-an-answer

I flagged [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19113705/806549) as Not An Answer and just saw it declined, which I hadn't seen coming. For posterity, here is the answer, which is by the OP of the question:

> Sorry for the late answer , I've found another way for this . as you said , using DataSource but What I would like to know now , is how to Load in it from SQL Server Database

I accept that there **could** be an answer, albeit well-hidden, in there - `using DataSource` - but it looks more like a comment to the [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19076069/806549) on the question, where it says:

> You then assign this to the GridControl.DataSource property

But even if it is not a comment, then there is still:

> but What I would like to know now

As I read it, the only way to make this a real answer would be to edit it to:

> [As you said](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19076069/806549): The solution is to use DataSource

Am I wrong here?

Comment: NAA flags are treated quite inconsistently in my view

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Yeah, probably. For a broader discussion on NAA or Other, I've created [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/199456/213634) question.

Comment: I've pinged the mod responsible in case he's around to clarify this, but so far as I can tell this was a simple mistake - possibly just a mis-click. FWIW: generally-speaking, NAA flags are handled pretty consistently, @David - but there are a LOT of NAA flags on SO, so even a small number of errors is gonna show up. Generally-speaking, I'd prefer a small handful of bad answers that took a little bit longer to be deleted than a small handful of good ones that have to be salvaged.

Comment: @Shog9 Thanks. My personal experience is that a significant proportion of my NAA flags are declined or disputed. I had one today and even asked a question here on meta. I think the mods should be more adventurous with NAA.

Comment: I checked your flag history, @David - the only semi-recent declined NAA flags were on [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18676392/writealltext-not-working/18676451#18676451) and [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17640526/delphi-tchromium-load-from-variable-function-not-working/17640980#17640980) which I think are reasonable answers (of course, the latter was edited substantially). You did have one *disputed* earlier, but that's the result of a 10K user disputing it - there's nothing a moderator can do about that.

Comment: @Shog9 I don't understand all this talk of 10k users and disputed. The disputed answer is as clear an NAA as I can imagine, bar nonsense spam. And I don't see how you can regard something starting "This won't solve your problem" as an answer. Opening with a confession to NAA, but declined. I think I have an understanding of NAA that differs from the mods.

Comment: You can read about disputed flags [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/95275/what-is-a-disputed-flag), @David. I tend to agree that the answer where your flag was disputed wasn't intended to answer the question (although it does seem to have been useful in prompting the asker to provide code to reproduce the problem), so I've deleted it. The first answer I linked to is a tough call though: yes, it's clearly not intended to answer *the question asked*, but it *is* intended to help teach the asker how to write code that's easier to debug - personally, I think that's a useful answer.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan this case was a mistake on my part. I do my darnedest to be consistent with my flags. This one slipped through the cracks.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This was completely my mistake.

I was trying to clear flags while my code was compiling, and I was probably going faster than I should.

You are correct, that is not an answer, and careful me would have deleted the answer.

*Quick explanation of my thought process:*

I read -

> I've found another way for this

And assumed the following text was explaining his solution. The rest of the text passed my "Does it have a `?` in it test as well.

Thanks for calling me out on this. I'll be more careful in the future. Feel free to comment here if you'd like to have more of a dialog.

Comment: Was your profile pic taken while you were reviewing some spam flags??

Comment: @AdamRackis haha, that's the explanation I will be using from now on. Thanks!

Comment: Clearly, you should take care to ensure your code takes much longer to compile in the future. Obligatory mention of XKCD that I'm not linking to but really want to!

Comment: Thanks for the answer. No need for an extended discussion here, I was just really puzzled especially wrt whether this was one of those that was not obvious enough in itself.

Comment: @TimPost Sadly I'm working on bringing compile time down right now.

Comment: @jjnguy FYI, the same answer, I presume, has been brought up here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/200369/213634

Comment: @AndersUP ha, yeah. Thanks for answering it so quickly.

Comment: @jjnguy NP. Figured I'd provide what I knew, yet still ping you and give you the chance to correct if you disagreed.

Answer (score 2):

Even if you are right (and I think you are), you must remember that:

- Flags are dealt with fast
- Mods don't need to be experts in field of the question

It means that if it looks like an answer, not an answer flag is likely to be refused. You can always downvote, comment, and in situations like this consider very low quality or (if removal is really necessary and downvotes aren't enough) custom reason flag.

Comment: Yeah, I know all of the above. I'm actually preparing a broader question on how frequently to use the custom reason, as I was moving away from that.

Comment: @AndersUP using others would bypass the 10k tools and might bother the mods for cases like this. I'd seen the *answer* as comment, too and assume that sometimes an error might happen on side of the *flagger* as well as on the side of a mod.

Comment: Broader discussion: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/199456/213634