# "Not an Answer" flag disputed

Tags: discussion, not-an-answer, disputed-flags

I'm highly curious to know why a particular answer which was flagged by me as "Not an Answer" was rejected with the status *disputed*?

[This is the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19239150/2024761) I'm talking about.

Just to be sure, I double checked this link, [How to Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) and found that the answer which I had flagged did not fit the bill at all.

Is that just because the answer was big(more than 3 lines is considered big these days) with a code snippet, that my *NAA* flag was disputed or what?

If you look at the answer, the person who posted the answer has also put an edit saying **Edit: I didn't read this carefully enough, your code already has it.**. How can such an answer actually be an answer(or even come close to answering that question)?

Comment: Why the downvote? If you don't agree with me, please share your views on why that answer should not be removed.

Comment: It seems like a very bad (perhaps even wrong) answer, that doesn't mean its not an answer though. Downvote bad/wrong answers, don't flag them

Comment: The answerer has posted the code snippet which the OP already has in the code. How can a part of the question be an answer(even the worse possible answer) to it? It doesn't even meet any of the said points in the *How to Answer* link either.

Comment: @R.J NAA is for those cases where it is *obvious* that this is not an answer. The case you mention above should be flagged with Other -> Explanation where you explain that this is not an answer *because* it is only a copy of OPs code (or some such). See for instance [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/199456/213634) discussion.

Comment: @AndersUP - So you mean to say that I might have flagged it under a wrong tag? Well, I hadn't thought about that. Thanks for the info! :)

Comment: @All - Hurray!:) I re-raised the flag with a detailed explanation about the answer and why I felt it must be removed and it was taken down almost immediately.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's a poor answer, but as everyone admits, the answerer *attempted to answer the question*:

The OP's edit:

> Edit: I didn't read this carefully enough, your code already has it.

The Commenter:

> OP already has that. Did you even have a look at the code before posting this answer?! Edit - Now that you've realized it, do you mind taking down this answer?

And in the comments above:

> It seems like a very bad (perhaps even wrong) answer, that doesn't mean its not an answer though.

That means, however poor that answer is, it is still *an answer*.

A post is *Not an answer* when it does not even attempt to address the question. Think:

- An answer that is actually its own stand-alone question
- A comment on another answer
- A post that has nothing to do with anything even remotely related to the current topic, such as, "I like bananas."

There are other posts that aren't really good answers, but are answers:

- Just a link to the documentation, or a blog, or some external resource that addresses the problem
- A literal answer, "Can I do this in Language X?" A: "No".
- A rhetorical answer, "Do you really want to run `GC.Collect()` in a loop?
- Addressing the OPs code, "Your code is subject to SQL injection attacks -- here's how to solve that"
- Answers that are entirely wrong, or have technical inaccuracies (we have a declination reason for just this)

In these cases, it is helpful to know *exactly* what you believe is wrong with the answer, and what you think we as moderators should do about it.  I have exactly four options when it comes to addressing a flagged "Not an answer" (or even a `Custom -> Other` flag) post:

- Delete the post
- Edit the post
- Leave a comment for the OP
- Do nothing

Your flag should state which action would you like a moderator to take, and why you want them to take it.

Comment: Your last line *Your flag should state which action would you like a moderator to take, and why you want them to take it.* is exactly what I had missed(and was hoping someone would tell me that). Thanks for such a detailed info!:)

Comment: Disagree. "I didn't read this carefully enough, your code already has it" means that it explicitly does **not** answer the question.

Comment: But I like bananas :(