# Why is my flag on this question "disputed"?

Tags: discussion, support, flags, disputed-flags

Curious to know if I did something wrong in flagging this question as I see the flag is disputed?

The answer in question is very clearly not an answer to the question at all - not even remotely related to it. It looks just weird - like someone meant to answer a different question.

I've never seen a disputed flag, and I just read a few meta questions about disputed flags - and the answers covered justification of bad answers, wrong answers etc... but I can't see an answer covering the scenario of a total non-sequitur that isn't just a valid "Not an answer".

The answer in question is here:

[How do I stop the Visual Studio Output window displaying the logger name of log4net output?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9174775/how-do-i-stop-the-visual-studio-output-window-displaying-the-logger-name-of-log4/20702019#20702019)

It seems to fall into the "not an answer" category as described here: ["Not an Answer" flag disputed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/200382/not-an-answer-flag-disputed?rq=1)

Comment: Note that disputed!=declined. But also a moderator is not expected to have subject level knowledge and to someone outside the area it does look like a terrible terrible answer

Comment: OK, so is the purpose of disputing the flag in this case to draw attention to it until a moderator who is an SME can look at it?

Comment: Maybe this was (miss)handled by someone from the 10k tools (flags) without inspecting the  whole task.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're right. This does not answer the given question. As such I've voted down and to delete, as well as flag it again. It has been removed.

A disputed flag means that someone counterflagged your flag (with the "This post has invalid flags", and a moderator agreed with him, or that the answer has been edited).