# Flag raised was rejected. How to re-flag the post?

Tags: discussion, flags, declined-flags

So, I am trying to be a vigilant member of Stack Overflow.

I flagged a few posts, and noticed that some of them were rejected/disputed.

Of course, my little ego was bruised (just joking) and I went back to check the flagged posts.

I still stand by my flags, but I apparently can't re-flag them.

Is there a way I can get a moderator's attention in that scenario?

Here are some examples :

[When should foreign keys be used?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18930783/when-should-foreign-keys-be-used/18930896#18930896)

In this case, the OP himself says that the answer is not related to his question. Yet, my flag (not an answer) was declined.

['string[]' does not contain a definition for 'Cast'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11222256/string-does-not-contain-a-definition-for-cast/19259618#19259618)

These flags were mainly raised when I was reviewing 'Late Answers'. So, from what I understood, you just don't down-vote irrelevant posts, you flag them too (if necessary), when doing the reviews?

Comment: The decline reason was also wrong there. Here's a better one: *flags should not be used to indicate technical inaccuracies, or an altogether wrong answer*.

Comment: So, if I see a wrong answer, what should I do?

Comment: @Somya You downvote it.

Comment: @Mysticial, in the second example, the answer is no where related to the question. Still not flag it and just downvote it? Sorry, a tad confused because it says - 'Mark it as not an answer - This was posted as an answer, but it does not attempt to answer the question. It should possibly be an edit, a comment, another question, or deleted altogether.'

Comment: @Somya The poster evidently *did* make an attempt to answer the question; it's just that the attempt was evidently incorrect.

Comment: @Somya: The answer in the second example still looks like an attempt.  The answerer was not asking another question altogether, thanking someone, or asking the OP for more information.

Comment: Actually, the answer in the second example is no where related to the question. Also, if I just simple down-vote a post, when doing a review, won't that be a bad review?

Comment: @Somya No, my understanding is that downvoting a bad answer will pass the audit.

Comment: Right. So, this is just the case of different moderators taking different approach. I failed a few audits in the past, when I just down-voted the post.

Comment: See also [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/199456/213634) discussion.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's a difference between "not an answer to the question," and the flag reason "Not an answer."

- The former is perfectly allowed, and not a good enough reason for deletion. If the answer given doesn't answer the question, feel free to downvote and let the answerer know.
- "Not an answer", when referring to the flag reason, refers to when the post doesn't even attempt to make an answer. Examples include making a post that's just another question, or a post that just says "so-and-so's answer worked for me too, thanks!"

So, in this case, please don't flag it (for moderator attention or otherwise); the post *is* an answer; just not what the asker was looking for. Quoting what **animuson** put as a comment: *flags should not be used to indicate technical inaccuracies, or an altogether wrong answer.*

Comment: Thanks, Dennis. What should I possibly flag this as then?

Comment: Don't flag at all. See what animuson posted as a comment

Comment: Hmmm, I have edited my question with more info. Basically, I was told by a moderator that when reviewing posts (first time posts or late answers), you flag the posts, and not just down-vote them.

Comment: @Somya Interesting, I've never actually seen anyone suggest that you flag an incorrect answer.

Comment: I swear on peanut butter, I was told to flag the posts or else they will fail me in the audit. And the cruel people actually did.

Comment: For what it's worth, audits are computerized, and they're not infallible. It could very well be that the audit system made a mistake there; because it's fairly agreed upon that you do not flag an answer simply because it's wrong or doesn't quite answer the question.

Comment: Will keep that in mind that. Sulking ends here.