# Why is my "not an answer" flag disputed?

Tags: discussion, not-an-answer, disputed-flags

I flagged [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20868248/1493698) as "not an answer" but it came out disputed.

> I think your'e looking for something like this:
>
> ```php
> function createDownloadScript() {
>     if (PayToADeveloper()) {
>         return true;
>     } else {
>         GoogleItAndTryThingsByYourself();
>     }
> }
> ```

[image: flag disputed]

How is this even an attempt to answer the question? This is such a joke answer. And the question is terrible too. Can someone help clean up this mess?

And in case something like this happens again in the future, should I reflag this as "not an answer", or flag it for moderator attention?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a disputed flag?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/95275/what-is-a-disputed-flag)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Obviously an oversight on the part of the moderator. That is clearly not an answer.

> And in case something like this happens again in the future, should I reflag this as "not an answer", or flag it for moderator attention?

No, and I don't believe the system will let you even select "not an answer" a second time. If it was overlooked *once*, then your flag was not detailed enough. If it really isn't an answer, cast a custom flag and further explain why it's not an answer. That will help ensure it does get deleted the second time around.

Comment: If it's disputed it's because of a 10Ker.

Comment: @hichris123 It still requires a moderator to dismiss it.

Comment: True. Didn't see the timespan on it.