# What will the status of a flag be if the OP deletes the question before triage completes?

Tags: support, flags, disputed-flags, triage

Just a few minutes ago, when I checked my flags. I noticed the following for a question I had recently flagged.

[image: flag image]

The content of the involved question consisted only of the text of the exception. So I had left the following comment on it, when I initially read it (from memory, as the question is now deleted and I cannot go back and check it verbatim).

> The exception seems quite clear, do you have a question?

A while later, this solicited the following response from the question's author:

> I am not here to play the question and answer game, I just want the solution.

At this point, concluding that OP had no intention of improving this low quality question or add what he had attempted himself to find an answer, I first flagged the question and next his comment as "not constructive".

Checking back on this a bit later, I noticed that the flag on the question was "disputed", the question deleted and the flag on the comment marked as helpful.

From [What is a disputed flag?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/95275/what-is-a-disputed-flag) I understand that a disputed flag results from it being reviewed, and dismissed as neither helpful nor declined.

I also just checked the [flowchart for a question's life cycle](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/288387/2573395) and it does not include what happens if the OP deletes the question him/herself, before triage takes place. Does this also lead to dismissing the flag and it receiving the status "disputed"? If not, what will the status of the flag be if OP deletes it before triage takes place?

As an "add-on" question: was there a different course of action I should have taken in this case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The flag would have been disputed by the triage review process. If the review completed as "Looks OK" or "Should Be Improved", any flags on it [will be disputed](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/289386/are-raised-flags-during-triage-disputed-if-others-disagree). The OP then decided to delete the question after that happened on his own volition.

If the OP deleted the question *before* any reviews had completed, the flag would have been marked as "helpful".

Comment: That is helpful to know. Care to address the final "add-on" part of my question?

Comment: @Alex: I don't think so.