# How do moderators increase/reduce a user's flag weight when they flag incorrectly?

Tags: discussion, flag-weight

I flagged some questions/answers as "doesn't belong here" or "needs moderator attention". Some of them were rejected, and my flag weight is now down to 80.

By reading [What is flag weight?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/80170/what-is-flag-weight), I know my flag weight will be reduced when my "offensive" and "spam" flags expire in two days, but I still have some questions:

1. How does Stack Overflow deal with a user's flag weight when "doesn't belong here" or "needs moderator attention" are marked as incorrect?
2. Is there a tool to let moderators manage (accept or reject) all flags?
3. Is it the moderator's choice to accept or reject flags manually to add/reduce flag weight?

Comment: What difference do you see between a tool and a manual acceptance/rejection? Moderators can dismiss individual flags and it's manual in the "I have to click a button" sense, but there are moderator-only *tools* needed to view and respond to current flags.

Comment: @Anna Lear, I want to know how the flag weight were be reduced, not how to view current flags.

Comment: @Roy Your sentences are just ungrammatical enough to be confusing. Are you asking what will happen to your weight when flags are rejected, or how mods go about rejecting flags?

Comment: @Michael Mrozek I am sorry for my sentences. my question is "how moderators go about rejecting flags?"

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think you're asking what moderators actually do to control a flag's outcome. This is what a flag looks like to a moderator:

[image: Example flag]

They have some common options built-in, "close question" and "delete question". Using either of those will automatically dismiss the flag as valid, and the user will gain the appropriate amount of flag weight.

If they don't take one of those actions they'll need to dismiss the flag manually with the "no further action..." button. That pops up a dialog like this:

[image: Flag dismissal dialog]

Naturally, choosing "valid" will mark the flag as valid and increase the flagger's flag weight; "invalid" will decrease their weight.

Comment: -1 - pandas are satanic beasts

Comment: @Shog9 Oh, I loathe pandas. The flag is obviously invalid

Comment: So, if moderators have only valid and invalid buttons how did I end up with a disputed flag? Do moderators click both the buttons at the same time? ;-) Man, that must require great talent to press the button at the exact same moment. :-)

Comment: @Siva 10k users can review the list of all generic flags (things other than "needs moderator attention") and can flag them as "invalid" if they disagree. Then no matter what happens your [flag weight won't change](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/95017/how-should-we-handle-flag-weight-for-invalid-flags/95029#95029), and the flag will [show up as disputed](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/95275/what-is-a-disputed-flag)

Comment: You need two mouses, computers, and monitors, to click both at the same time, all required equipment for becoming a moderator.