# Has the disputed flag message changed?

Tags: discussion, flags

I know how disputed flags work. Today, I reviewed a "not an answer" flag and marked it as invalid.

I've later seen a disputed message with this reason:

> invalid flag
>
> disputed - a moderator reviewed your flag, but found no evidence to
>   support it

Given that disputed flags are in the ["Both flags are correct" category](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/95017/how-should-we-handle-flag-weight-for-invalid-flags/95029#95029),

Is this message *applicable only to my flag* or is this message also for the original flagger?

Or put otherwise, *are all disputed flags now shown this message* (or similar decline reason)?

I've run out of flags for today to test this further.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That message belongs to the "invalid flag" part, if a moderator declares your flag invalid they now have to supply a reason, the message you see is one of the predefined reasons for declining a flag.

The message has nothing to do with the flag being disputed, though it seems to be displayed in a misleading way. I would assume that the decline message was meant for the original flagger, so the message should not be shown for the user that disputed the flag.

Comment: So if this message is applicable to (a) the original flag by somebody being invalid or (b) my flag being invalid or (c) both cases. You're saying this is situation (b) ?

Comment: The message means that a moderator declined the flag on that post, this would mean your "dispute" flag being valid. It seems to be an edge case with disputed flags, as flag handling always works on *all* flags on a post, mods can't treat flags on the same post different. It is very misleading to show this message at all for a dispute flag.