# Does disagreeing with a flag add towards your flag count?

Tags: support, badges, flags, 10k-tools

You are able to "disagree" with a flag when you [go here](https://stackoverflow.com/tools/flagged?subtype=notananswer), do those disagreements get added to one's flag queue to be marked as helpful or not?

[image]

There was a previous question asking about [flag weight](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/95017/155556) which no longer is in play. I am asking if these "disagree" flags go towards earning the flag badges.

Comment: There are 10k users who _haven't_ managed to flag 500 posts?

Comment: @Ben hehe yep. I have been too busy answering questions.

Comment: @Ben there are [lots](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/84620/10k-users-without-marshal-badge)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. If you don't believe me, try it and observe the number of helpful flags shown in your profile.

Answer (score 4):

When you mark a flag as invalid, your own flag is marked as disputed.

[image: screenshot]

Those flags are shown in your flagging history under "disputed"; they don't count as useful flags, and don't allow you to get a badge for useful flags.

As for flag weight, it is not shown anymore to users, but it is still internally used to order the flags in the page showing the flagged posts. If users keep to wrongly flag posts, their flags will be shown after the other ones.