# Disputed Flag on Low-Quality post

Tags: support, flags, low-quality-posts

Several minutes ago there was a [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14134052/app-running-only-once) asked on SO, which when originally posted, was just a terrible post, which was hard to determine what was being asked, and there was absolutely no details provided, for which I flagged it as `Low-Quality`. The OP has less then 10k rep.

This was the entirety of the original post:

> I am working on an app which should run only once after the Installation,Even the launcher should be disabled after I quit it

In my Flag-History, I am now seeing that the flag was deemed `disputed`, and I am confused as to why.

I read that if a post is flagged of low quality, and it is edited, the flags become `disputed` because they are supposedly supposed to mark questions that are irrecoverable by edits..

The question has since undergone 3 edits by the OP, none of which added much information that would help the community to help them, and the question has also been Closed as `not a real question`, yet my flag is still marked as `disputed`..

Does this non-helpful flag have any affect on my flag-history?

Comment: I had that twice yet. Don't worry that *bad* flags won't hurt you.

Comment: I also do not understand why a flag is disputed when 'someone' edits the question.  It does not necessarily make the question better.  I had a case where some just formatted the stacktrace, which was the entire body of the question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Does this non-helpful flag have any affect on my flag-history?

It is marked as disputed and displayed alongside accepted and declined. [Disputed flags do not affect the flag weight](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/95029/152859), but if you have a lot of flags **declined**, then your flags are displayed lower on the review queues for mods.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know:

- **disputed** is at least an other user questions the validity of the flag.
- **declined** means, a moderator has declined your flag.

It is no real disaster if some flags are declined.

Comment: Like he said in his question, VLQ flags get auto-dismissed if the post gets edited. It doesn't require another user to intervene.