# Why was my low quality flag disputed?

Tags: discussion, flags, low-quality-posts

I marked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18105496/the-new-project-add-afnetworking-library-occur-some-errors) question as very low quality, but my flag was disputed.

After reading the question again the phrase "I have got the answer here" might indicate that this is not a question at all. So I may have used the wrong flag.

I think we can all agree that the question should be closed, but I don't want to flag again without making sure.

Did I use the wrong flag? Does it even matter?

For future reference this is the question in it's entirety:

> Undefined symbols for architecture i386: "_SecCertificateCopyData", referenced from: -[AFURLConnectionOperation connection:willSendRequestForAuthenticationChallenge:] in AFURLConnectionOperation.o 跟着有八九个这样的错误，不知道缺什么？
>
> I have got the answer here-->[APPLE MACH-O LINKED ERROR After adding AFNetworking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18021362/apple-mach-o-linked-error-after-adding-afnetworking)
>
> thanks @Martin R

**EDIT:** it's on hold now. I'm not sure if I was just too impatient, it was put on hold as a result of this post.

Let me rephrase the question:
I can't vote to close yet.
Since I have absolutely no clue what the OP is looking for I could not edit the question and a comment feels pointless.
Since I got the question as a review I felt obliged to do SOMETHING. What should I have done instead of flagging it as very low quality?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Disputed Flag on Low-Quality post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/161303/disputed-flag-on-low-quality-post) and of [What is a disputed flag?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/95275/what-is-a-disputed-flag)

Comment: Definitely put on hold as a result of this post. We Meta folk like to use our close votes.

Comment: Just to answer your edit: yes, you should have used one of the "does not belong here" flags. The reasons you can choose from are equivalent to the reasons a question can be closed. "Unclear what you're asking" would have been fine. As would one of the appropriate "off topic" reasons.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is little point in flagging a question like that as "low quality".

I mean, sure, you're right, it's obviously poor quality. But that flag is for content that requires a moderator's intervention. For questions, a "low quality" flag really means more like ["delete this immediately, it should not be on the site any longer"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/93606/153008).

All this question needs is to be closed. And possibly edited. You can do either or both of those things yourself, without involving a moderator.

Comment: Meh, I see that as falling flat in the 'oh good grief just delete' category, and I decline _a lot_ of VLQ flags for being over zealous. This is one of the rare times that the flag was used appropriately, in my opinion.

Comment: I can't vote to close yet. Should I have used the "unclear what you're asking " flag or just hope somebody else takes care of it?

Comment: you should Ask Questions in the Comments

Comment: @Tim Hmm. I *agree* with that. But hardly a day passes on Meta that I don't see moderators telling people this. Truth is, I haven't seen a low quality flag brought to Meta yet that I wouldn't mark as helpful and delete the post outright. So I still don't know where the line is drawn. I think the mods need to harden up and hit that "delete" button more.

Comment: @CodyGray "For questions, a "low quality" flag really means more like "delete this immediately, it should not be on the site any longer"" - this one is **a perfect example of such a question.** We ain't need none of this type of noise on SO.

Comment: And look, this question was closed as a duplicate, and *by a Stack Overflow moderator* no less. Normally I'd think that was completely reasonable, except that [we're specifically told to go to Meta to protest when one of our "low quality" flags is declined and we disagree](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/160755/153008). We're in a real catch-22 here. cc @Tim