# Separate "invalid flags" in the flag statistics

Tags: feature-request, 10k-tools, statistics, flags, invalid-flags

As per the discussion on [Why do “Invalid Flag” flags get disputed?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/161651/189976), the "helpful"/"disputed" resolution of "invalid flag" flags is giving limited or zero value on whether the "invalid flag" flag was justified. I therefore suggest to exclude "invalid flag" flags completely from the flag statistics, i.e. make it a seperate category of flags in the right column in the Flagging history page.

I'm not really a statistics hunter, but I keep an eye on my "helpful" flagging ratio to know whether I do a good job or not. "Invalid flag" flags corrupt this ratio and makes it quite complicated.

Comment: it would probably make sense to also rename these from "invalid" to "invalidated"

Comment: @gnat +1 for that name change. It is all-over a confusing thing with them :)

Comment: Why not just a total "helpful flags" count at the end of the statistics? That's the only thing missing (it's in the profile page, but not in the flag history).

Comment: @bfavaretto I'm not sure whether it' unclear. I know how many helpful flags I do have. My concern is to clean the helpful/unhelpful statistics from the mess generated by "invalid flags" I issue.