# Invalid flags count as disputed

Tags: feature-request, flags, disputed-flags, invalid-flags

I went through the flag queue and flagged some *not an answer* flags as invalid. (We have sooo many of these NAA flags, it scares me).

Flagging as invalid automatically makes my flags *disputed* [as explained here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/161645/why-do-invalid-flag-flags-get-disputed).

[image: invalid flags]

Does having many disputed flags anyhow damage my reputation as flagger?
Can we change that behaviour to make these flags helpful or to indicate that my disputed flag was correct or not?

Comment: I don't think changing to helpful would be the right thing, but having something to tell whether you disputed a flag, or your flag was disputed would help.

Answer (score 8):

The "invalid flag" option serves *only* to dispute other flags, and itself doesn't address issues with posts in any way. This is why *both* flags are marked disputed and it would not make sense to change it so that "invalid flag" is considered a helpful flag.

Note that the "disputed" outcome takes effect immediately after you dispute a flag, so there is no such thing as an "invalid flag" option being "correct" or not. This also means that whatever eventual action a moderator takes, the flags are counted as disputed and cannot be marked helpful or declined. The good news is that disputed flags do not affect your flagging ability at all.

Comment: *whatever eventual action a moderator takes, the flags are counted as disputed and cannot be marked helpful or declined.* Looking at my recent flag history I see one invalid-flag entry that is marked helpful. Funny.