# Change disputed/invalid flag to helpful if moderators ultimately close/delete the post

Tags: feature-request, flags

So the purpose of the invalid, disputed, helpful system is to give feedback about what posts should be flagged.

But when a post gets closed/deleted doesn't this imply that some flags on it might have been correct, even if at some point those flags were called invalid/disputed.

So I'm proposing that in the cases that a flag reflected the ultimate reason the post was closed/deleted that these flags be changed to helpful. Since in these cases the flags were correct, and the feedback to the users should reflect that.

Comment: The question could be closed/post deleted for other reasons than the flag was raised for.

Comment: Maybe I should edit it to reflect only when the flag was raised with the correct reason?  Edited and updated to reflect only when flags were correct

Comment: Meh, does it matter?

Comment: +1 but I have reservations.  In principle, a question can be eventually closed as a duplicate of a better formulated question that did not even exist at the time the older, worse question was voted as a duplicate of something unrelated.  Likewise, the flag and the eventual closure may be based on a quite different edit revisions or retagging.  I still think that the new behavior would do more good than harm.

Comment: It seems like that would only be a concern after a long time period. So maybe put a time limit where this would apply, like up to a couple of days.  I would wager that's 95% of cases anyway

Answer (score 9):

We get flags like:

> "Plz send teh codez, it has been three hours already and there iz no anz".

This proposal would add flag weight to those flags instead of decreasing it. That would be bad and there isn't a solution to that.

In the case of disputed flags it also [pits one flagger against another](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/95029/153020), incentivising "taking the law into your own hands" (e.g. unhelpful harassing comments) to make sure the outcome gets that coveted "helpful" mark.

In the grand scheme of things incrementing a privately held counter by changing a "helpful"/"not helpful" mark makes very little difference in respect of the *raison d'être*: making the Internet a better place.

Comment: Sure there is a solution. Just send teh codez already!

Comment: You make some good points that I definitely didn't think of.