# Permanent Flag Weight History Link on User Profile

Tags: bug, status-completed, profile-page, flag-weight, flag-history

The link to the user's flagging history should always be available to them (but not to the public) in their profile.

Example for my profile: [Flagging History](https://stackoverflow.com/users/flag-weight/146610)

At the moment, the link isn't displayed when the user's flag weight is 100, so they can't see feedback if they happen to have made an equal number of helpful and declined flags: the weight is invisible and so the link doesn't appear.

Comment: I think this is a good idea.  It's visible when it's below or above 100, why not just leave it all the time?

Comment: Does it disappear if you return to 100 after having accepted/declined flags? If so, then this is a *bug*. It's only supposed to be not visible when you don't have any flagging history yet.

Comment: Just to be sure: you're not asking for the link to be *publicly* visible/accessible to other users, right? (Hence, the link to *your* flag weight doesn't add anything to the feature request?)

Comment: Just like the revision history for posts that haven't been edited (but could have been deleted/undeleted, closed, etc.), the link is not there, but the page is.

Comment: Indeed, from [Flag weight audit](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/84757/flag-weight-audit/85150#85150), about the implementation: *"If your flag weight is not visible (on account of sitting at 100), you can also access this by going to `<siteurl>/users/flag-weight/<userid>`, substituting for the site in question and your own user ID."*

Comment: @animuson yes, if your score returns to 100 it disappears. and it's not a bug; they know about it, just a petty feature they probably don't have the desire to tweak, which is understandable i guess.

Comment: @Arjan Yes, visible to the user only. If you took the time to read my post, you'll notice the link you mentioned is already there. I am requesting a permanent link be available to the users from their own profile, as the history is more important than the specific score. It should be a tiny thing to ask to have done.

Comment: Well, if *you* took the time to read my comment then *maybe* you could see that things were confusing rather than suggesting people haven't read the post. As for downvoting (which I did not so far): on Meta, that also means people don't want the feature, or don't want the team to spend time on it (which is what I feel right now).

Comment: @Arjan What were you confused about? The post has not been edited in any way other than adding a flag and the down-voter header. As for spending time on it, I'm no wizard and don't know SO's innards intimately, but I would bet it's less than an hour's work. *They* will decide whether it's worth their time or not. Thanks for the comments anyhow.

Comment: I feel *"a link to the user's flagging history always be available from his/her profile"* (and posting a link to your history) is easily confused for making it publicly visible, hence my "just to be sure". Maybe that even caused some of the downvotes. I'd say: rather than responding in a comment, edit the question to make it explicit. Cheers! That aside, let's clean up some of our comments?

Comment: The request is not very clearly worded. Instead of bitching about people not understanding it, why not make it clearer? (I agree with the request though, +1)

Comment: Any other Id value passed to the URL returns a 404. Making a link public would mean errors in abundance changing permissions - *"Make a user's flag weight history available to other users"* is a different question and was not what was asked.

Comment: So we can have *more* complaints about flag weight?  Absolutely not.

Comment: This is no longer relevant, since now [only the number of flags are listed](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/84859/we-dont-need-to-see-flag-weight/119709#119709).

Comment: chucking completed ... cause we have no ... status no longer relevant

Comment: @waffles - just noticed. it looks good.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The feature requested has been added.

On a user's own profile, one can see (between 'profile views' and 'recent names') a count of the user's own `Helpful Flags`. While the count number reflects only those flags deemed helpful, it is a link to the flag decision history for all of one's own flags, both helpful and unhelpful.

EDIT:
The title of the state may be misleading, but your `Helpful Flags: #Count` will appear after a single flag, regardless of whether it is successful or declined. This is a good thing as it will ensure users with bad luck flagging can see their history and get feedback to do it better next time.

Very nice work guys. Thank you.

Comment: **at least 1 flag** is the implemented condition. **Successful is not mandatory** - I just tested this with my account at SQA (http://sqa.stackexchange.com/users/1036/gnat - link visible only to me and mods). Link is displayed in profile for 1 declined / 0 helpful flags

Comment: @gnat - thanks for clearing that up. that makes it better in that someone who is new and simply gets all of them declined, they can still access their history.

Answer (score 2):

If the question was about link to flagging history disappearing from profile, like this one: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/119127/flag-history-disappears-from-profile-by-irrelevant-condition-weight-100 then I would be all for having the behavior such that **users with non-empty flagging history always see that link**.

However in [its current wording](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/revisions/117008/7) question reads wider than that. As far as I can tell it implies a suggestion for history link to appear even before user submits their first flag:

> a link to the user's flagging history always be available from his/her profile.

## Please, no

I am rather a newbie here (as of now my membership at SO is about 6x shorter than [yours](https://stackoverflow.com/users/146610)) that's why I clearly recall that **at first glance profile page felt quite complicated** - even without flagging history, review tab etc.

Back then, stuff like flagging history page would mean to me nothing more than yet another cryptic gadget, making matters only more complicated.

> It is nice to see what changes are accepted/aren't and read one's history even if the current weight is 100 (making the score invisible).

I think it is *nice* only to those having at least some knowledge about flagging. For a typical newbie this is not the case I'm afraid.

Comment: Normally, the link is shown only after a user has made their first flag. But at the moment, there's a bug where a user who has made an equal number of helpful and declined flag doesn't see the link.

Comment: @Gilles so, is this question about the bug? per my reading, its current title and first sentence suggest otherwise. If it was like "Permanent Flag Weight History Link disappears on User Profile" / "The link to the user's flagging history should not disappear..." then I'd upvote it in a heartbeat

Comment: [I reported the bug](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/119127/flag-history-not-shown-in-the-profile-when-the-flag-weight-is-100) (because a user had been confused by it on a site where I'm a mod), and my report was closed as a duplicate of this question.

Comment: @Gilles I see - my brain still boils trying to figure how to deal with this "widening duplicate". Things would be much simpler if this question was closed as duplicate of yours, not vice versa

Comment: I agree, especially since it's not clear to me whether one.beat.consumer wants the link there for users who've never flagged (which I'm weakly against). I've asked random to reopen, but in vain.

Comment: @Gilles I asked about the reasons for close: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/119275/are-these-questions-about-link-to-flagging-history-exact-duplicates

Comment: @Gilles - my apologies for taking so long replying, been working lots of overtime of late. honestly, I hadn't thought of the details that deep, but I would think, for users who are above X Reputation (say the 200 "youre participating rank", or 1000 "dedicated user") it stay on... or maybe as you suggest, only after the first time you have flagged and judgement has been passed on your flag. I personally favor the later because it is more closely aligned to the point.

Comment: @Gilles Just to clarify again, I only ever meant for the flag weight and decision history to be available on ones OWN profile. Not for another user to see my flag weight or decision history by visiting mine. The reason is to help me follow changes, but more importantly for me to learn what has been helpful to moderators, and what has been a waste of their time.