# What does empty "Flagging Summary" page mean when "helpful flags" is "1"?

Tags: bug, status-norepro, flag-history

When I visit my profile page, I see "helpful flags 1" where "1" is a hyperlink to the "Flagging Summary" page.

So, when I click "1", I get the "Flagging Summary" page and I see the page mostly empty. What does it mean?

Screenshot included below:

[image]

Comment: It probably means that you had 1 flag but it "poofed" from the system, and the 2 pages are using a different cache.  See if your profile page clears within 24 hours.

Comment: are you using [officially supported browser version](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/56161/which-browsers-are-officially-supported-and-what-else-do-i-need)? if yes then the way how summary is shown for you differs from implementation described in answer to this question: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/117008/permanent-flag-weight-history-link-on-user-profile

Comment: @BrockAdams My profile has been like this for the last one month.

Comment: @gnat I get the same results with Firefox 10.0.1 as well as Chrome 17.0.963.46 m.

Comment: On the flagging summary page, run this command: `$("#flag-stat-info-table tr").length` from either the JS console (Ctrl-Shift-K) or the Firebug console.  What is the result?

Comment: hm both FF 10 and Chrome 17 are currently marked as **unsupported (pre-"stable release" version)** at the official list

Comment: @gnat, I use both of those browsers and my profile and flag-summary pages all show correctly.  That is, on those SE sites where I never flagged, no link is present in the profile page. The link is not present in the static HTML (that is, it is not merely hidden), nor is it AJAXed in on pages that have the link.  So it seems unlikely that this is a browser issue.

Comment: You remember what you flagged? If you only flagged single comment, it explains this behavior as comment flags are not displayed in the flagging history but do count in the total count. (If helpful of course :))

Comment: @ShaDowWizArd, A summary/count of comment flags is shown in the flagging history.

Comment: @BrockAdams I executed `$("#flag-stat-info-table tr").length` on JS console. The output I got is: `0`.

Comment: Well, it looks like it's going to take a moderator or dev to figure this out.  Do you recall flagging anything at all (could the 1 count be right)? Did you have multiple user accounts and/or log-in problems?

Comment: Just flag an answer and you should be set :)

Answer (score 5):

This is a specific instance of the bug "[Flag counters not shown although I had flagged some comments](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/145400/191131)": You have raised **one helpful flag on a comment**, and **no flags on other posts** (questions/answers). Comment flags are not listed individually, but their total number should be shown on the right-hand side below "Your flagging history". However due to the above-mentioned bug, the flagging summary page is completely empty as long as you haven't flagged at least one non-comment post.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for bringing this issue up. This profile section does not exist in the current build of our sites, and so this is no longer an issue. :)